# Excel - Multiple Cell Ranges error 1004 when using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have one line of code that selects multiple cell ranges as follows:

```
Range("B9:M9,B12:M12,B15:M15,B18:M18,B21:M21,B24:M24,B27:M27,B30:M30,B33:M33,R9:AC9,R12:AC12,R15:AC15,R18:AC18,R21:AC21,R24:AC24,R27:AC27,R30:AC30,R33:AC33,AH9:AS9,AH12:AS12,AH15:AS15,AH18:AS18,AH21:AS21,AH24:AS24,AH27:AS27,AH30:AS30,AH33:AS33,AW9:BI9,AW12:BI12,AW15:BI15").Select
```

However, it looks like I am selecting too many cells as I get the error in the picture at the bottom of the question (error 1004).  If I remove some of the selection it works.

I decided to record a macro and see how it copes and it did the following code:

```
    Union(Range( _
    "AW24:BI24,AW27:BI27,AW30:BI30,AW33:BI33,B9:M9,B12:M12,B15:M15,B18:M18,B21:M21,B24:M24,B27:M27,B30:M30,B33:M33,R9:AC9,R12:AC12,R15:AC15,R18:AC18,R21:AC21,R24:AC24,R27:AC27,R30:AC30,R33:AC33,AH9:AS9,AH12:AS12,AH15:AS15,AH18:AS18,AH21:AS21,AH24:AS24,AH27:AS27" _
    ), Range("AW12:BI12,AW15:BI15,AW18:BI18,AW21:BI21")).Select
```

However, when I try to run the code again I get the same 1004 error.  Any help greatly appreciated

[image]

Full Code Below:

```
Sub updateSelectedMetric()
```

currentChosenMetric = Range("A4").Value

```
Range("B9:M9,B12:M12,B15:M15,B18:M18,B21:M21,B24:M24,B27:M27,B30:M30,B33:M33,R9:AC9,R12:AC12,R15:AC15,R18:AC18,R21:AC21,R24:AC24,R27:AC27,R30:AC30,R33:AC33,AH9:AS9,AH12:AS12,AH15:AS15,AH18:AS18,AH21:AS21,AH24:AS24,AH27:AS27,AH30:AS30,AH33:AS33").Select

'Union(Range( _
'    "AW24:BI24,AW27:BI27,AW30:BI30,AW33:BI33,B9:M9,B12:M12,B15:M15,B18:M18,B21:M21,B24:M24,B27:M27,B30:M30,B33:M33,R9:AC9,R12:AC12,R15:AC15,R18:AC18,R21:AC21,R24:AC24,R27:AC27,R30:AC30,R33:AC33,AH9:AS9,AH12:AS12,AH15:AS15,AH18:AS18,AH21:AS21,AH24:AS24,AH27:AS27" _
'    ), Range("AW12:BI12,AW15:BI15,AW18:BI18,AW21:BI21")).Select

Select Case currentChosenMetric
    Case "Waste (%)", "CiCL <1", "DSODA", "DCODA"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    Case "UPT", "Sales (U)", "CTF (U)"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    Case "RoS", "CTF to Sales"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "##.0"
    Case "Sales (£)", "Waste (£)"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "£#,##0"
End Select

Range("A1").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: You can only pass a 255 character string to Range. Break it up into shorter blocks.

Comment: The string setting the range cannot exceed 255 characters. But, is it convenient for you to all the time write such a code? Can't the discontinuous range be built using a piece of code using an algorithm (to be defined) to do it? When you manually do it, I suppose you have a specific logic to do it... And why should it be necessary to select? Shouldn't it be better to edit your question and share the code showing what you finally try accomplishing?

Comment: Additional code to show that the selection is to amend the formatting based on a chosen metric by the user.

Comment: Yes Named Range as suggested by @Rui is a good option. If you want to do this via VBA then I see a pattern in the range `Rows 9 to 33 with Step 3` and `B:M`,`R:AC`, `AH:AS` and `AW:BI`. A simply loop with Union can solve your issue ;) The only thing which is an outlier inthe above pattern is `AW:BI`.. Which I feel should have been `AX:BI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the selection seems to work...

```
    Range("R27:AC27,R30:AC30,R33:AC33,AH9:AS9,AH12:AS12,AH15:AS15,AH18:AS18,AH21:AS21,AH24:AS24,AH27:AS27,AH30:AS30,AH33:AS33,AW9:BI9,AW12:BI12,AW15:BI15").Select
Union(Selection, Range("B9:M9,B12:M12,B15:M15,B18:M18,B21:M21,B24:M24,B27:M27,B30:M30,B33:M33,R9:AC9,R12:AC12,R15:AC15,R18:AC18,R21:AC21,R24:AC24")).Select
```

Comment: The recorded macro was so close lol :)  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using named ranges for easier access. =)

Comment: oh, that could make even more sense.  Thank you for the additional idea.